# uniqid was installed but I can't use its function

Tags: javascript, npm

I installed uniqid from npm but when I use uniqid(), it return an error TypeError: _uniqid.uniqid is not a function

```
import { uniqid } from 'uniqid';


console.log(uniqid()) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your first line with `import uniqid from 'uniqid';`